# json into mysql5 by php5

Tags: php, mysql, json

i'm trying to put json_encoded strings containing html tags into mysql5. the problem is that the data in mysql seems automatically unescaped all "s. data is fed by POST and i'm using standard mysql_query.

if i print any json string into browser it shows as correctly escaped, \". but when inserted into mysql all \"s became "s. naturally unescaped "s make string non-json. any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_real_escape_string($s);
```

Comment: ...or parameterized (prepared) statements

Comment: You should probably add a link to the documentation and format that snippet as code. +1 for the (probably) helpful answer.